# Pouch DB Remote not working on Android Device

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I've have some Problems with PouchDB Sync on real Devices per remote.

Link to my Topic on Github: 
https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4783

I hope someone can give me a tip

Greetings

John

Comment: when is vm.toggleOnline = function () called..??

Comment: It is called in an extra html called ListView

Answer (score 0):

its really hard to predict the cause..!try this..! [see here..!](http://devgirl.org/2014/12/30/sync-data-using-pouchdb-in-your-ionic-framework-app/)

```
        if(window.Connection) {
            if(navigator.connection.type !== Connection.NONE) {
                var sync = vm.TodoDb.sync(vm.TodoRemoteDb)
                    .on('complete', function () {
                        //console.log('handle complete '+JSON.stringify(info));
                        sync.cancel();
                    })
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't solved my problem... Any other idea?